# Was slavery in islamic times different from how it was practiced by ISIS?

Tags: slavery

The practice of slavery was re-instituted by ISIS upon their capture of yazidi women in iraq. These women suffered immensely and were traumatized from capture, sale and coercive sex with their captors as it was known from their own testimonies. Would this be the accepted fate of such women in early islam from conquests and such?

Answer (score -4):

Yazid's didn't initiate war against ISIS and they were in Iraq for centuries. ISIS initiated war on them for no reason and then killed their males who didn't convert to Islam and abducted their females and forced sex on them.

To force sex on someone who is unwilling is rape and rape is a severe crime in Islam.

> Say, "My Lord has only forbidden immoralities - what is apparent of
> them and what is concealed - and sin, and **oppression without right**,
> and that you associate with Allah that for which He has not sent down
> authority, and that you say about Allah that which you do not know."
> Quran 7:33

There are lot of other issues that ISIS indulged in, like forced conversion and persecution of minorities.

This is all contrary to what Islam teaches. Prophet (s.a) even when his death was near was advising to be careful in the case of slave women. Slave woman should be given gift in presence of witness and she should accept it, before any sex can happen with them.

> And [also prohibited to you are all] married women except those your
> right hands possess.1 [This is] the decree of Allāh upon you. And
> lawful to you are [all others] beyond these, **[provided] that you
> seek them [in marriage] with [gifts from] your property, desiring
> chastity, not unlawful sexual intercourse.** So for whatever you enjoy
> [of marriage] from them, give them their due compensation as an
> obligation. And there is no blame upon you for what you mutually agree
> to beyond the obligation. Indeed, Allāh is ever Knowing and Wise.
> Quran 4:24

This verse and previous verse is about the forbidden people in marriage but it excludes slave woman provided they accept mahr(gift) and are ready for marriage.